# Replacing numbers into specific string

Tags: c#

I'm supposed to generate random numebers and then giveout the numbers but with different name.

I managed to create random numbers, but I stuck at the giving the right output:

My code:

```
static Random rnd = new Random();
public static int GetZufall()
{
    int random = rnd.Next(0, 10); // from 0 to 9
    return random;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many random numbers do you want: ");
    int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();
    int[] array = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        array[GetZufall()]++;
        //Console.WriteLine(GetZufall()); // Random numbers
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{i} : {array[i]}");
    }
    int maxValue = array.Max(); // Linq
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Most common value: " + maxValue);
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        string result = array.ToString();
        result = result.Replace("1", "X");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

So as you can see I've tried to convert the array to String and then replace each number with X.

#### Example:

Input: 5 random numbers
Output:

- 0: 0
- 1: 2
- 2: 0
- 3: 0
- 4: 3
- 5: 0
- 6: 0
- 7: 0
- 8: 0
- 9: 0

This output is right, but the next one should be like this:

- 0: 0
- 1: XX
- 2: 0
- 3: 0
- 4: XXX
- 5: 0
- 6: 0
- 7: 0
- 8: 0
- 9: 0

I've tried also using Regex `Regex r = new Regex("[0-9]"", RegexOptions.None);`

Comment: "*string result = array.ToString();*" -- you want `item.ToString` not `array.ToString` I suspect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First mistake is

```
string result = array.ToString();
```

should be

```
string result = item.ToString();
```

Here's one solution:

```
foreach (var item in array)
{
    string result = "";
    if (item == 0)
         result = "0";
    else
         for (int i = 0; i < item; i++)
             result += "X";                  
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

**UPDATE**

"If I would like to output it like 0 : XX , also the numbers of array in the front what should I do ?"

This should work:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var item in array)
{
    string result = "";
    result = count.ToString() + " : ";
    count++;
    for (int i = 0; i < item; i++)
        result += "X";
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: If I would like to output it like 0 : XX , also the numbers of array in the front what should I do ?

Comment: E.g. there are 2: 6 and the output 2: XXXXXX

Comment: Please see updated answer and let me know if that looks right.

Comment: Not exactly , I've got that result, it should be from 0 to 9, this takes the result.
Your solution: Input 2: 6 the output is 6 : XXXXXX it should be 2: XXXXXX

Comment: Not sure I completely understand. But try latest update.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing 1s with 'X'. You should use the values to add Xs like this:

```
foreach (int x in array)
{
    result = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)
        result += "X"
    if (result == "")
        result = "0";
}
```

Comment: Thank you also for the solution.